# Need to translate some UnityScript to C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I found code for my problem on internet, but I need it in C#, not UnityScript. I tried but I don't know how to fix some problems. I translated almost everything.

Original:

```
#pragma strict

var prefab : GameObject;

function Start () {
    spawn();
}

function Update () {

}

function GetPointOnMesh() : RaycastHit {
    var length : float = 100.0;
    var direction : Vector3 = Random.onUnitSphere;
    var ray : Ray = Ray(transform.position + direction*length,-direction);
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    GetComponent.<Collider>().Raycast (ray, hit, length*2);
    return hit;
}
    function spawn() {
        var randomPoint = GetPointOnMesh();
        var spawnPreferences = Instantiate(prefab, randomPoint.point, Quaternion.identity);
        spawnPreferences.transform.eulerAngles.y = Random.Range(0, 360);
    }
```

Half-translated to C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ResourceGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameObject prefab;

    void Start()
    {
        spawn();
    }

    RaycastHit GetPointOnMesh()
    {
        float length = 100.0f;
        Vector3 direction = Random.onUnitSphere;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position + direction * length, -direction);
        RaycastHit hit;
        GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, length * 2);
        return hit;
    }

    void spawn()
    {
        var randomPoint = GetPointOnMesh();
        var spawnPreferences = Instantiate(prefab, randomPoint.point, Quaternion.identity);
        spawnPreferences.transform.eulerAngles.y = Random.Range(0, 360);
    }

}
```

I don't know what variable type needs to be instead of var and there is a bug at last line "Object does not cointain definition for "transform".

Comment: Also remember one thing - Your script file name must be the same as the class. in this case, it should be ResourceGenerator.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
void spawn()
    {
        RaycastHit randomPoint = GetPointOnMesh();
        GameObject spawnPreferences= (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, randomPoint.point, Quaternion.identity);
        spawnPreferences.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,Random.Range(0, 360),0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for help guys. It's working. Now I can back to game making.

Comment: @Haker53535 Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to accept an answer if it helped you solve your problem - that way your question is marked as answered.